# How do I create new instance with reflections in java

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I have a quick question. How do I create a new instance with passing the parameters to the constructor? Since the GraphicObject can be any of the classes that extend it, I need to know somehow which class it is and here I have to use the class that extends it, so I'm trying reflection, but so far only null exception on this.

```
    GraphicObject decor = null;

    try {
        decor = decorator.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(GraphicObject.class).newInstance(mainGroup);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The class that should be reflected looks like this:

```
public class DecoratorLeft extends GraphicObjectDecorator {

// jei bus klaida, tai bus del to, kad neuzsaugom per konstruktoriu paduodamos reiksmes i global variable
GraphicObject decoratedGraphic = null;

public DecoratorLeft(GraphicObject decoratedGraphic) {
    super(decoratedGraphic);
    this.decoratedGraphic = decoratedGraphic;
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g, AlignStrategy align) {
    alignLeft();
    decoratedGraphic.draw(g, align);

    //drawAlignedLeft(g, decoratedGraphic, align);        
}
```

}

Here's the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at objprog1.Whiteboard.paintComponent(Whiteboard.java:157)
```

I modified again the try/catch statement with printstactrace and runtimeexception:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at objprog1.Whiteboard.paintComponent(Whiteboard.java:179)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5228)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3867)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:781)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at objprog1.Whiteboard.paintComponent(Whiteboard.java:182)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5228)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3867)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:781)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at objprog1.Whiteboard.paintComponent(Whiteboard.java:179)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: Could you add the stack-trace for the exception you are getting to your post?

Comment: It appears you're trying to assign the result of the `newInstance()` to a `GraphicObject` - is that assignable given that you're trying to construct a `GraphicObjectDecorator` ?

Comment: @millhouse, no I guess that's not what I want. I'm trying to create a new instance of the GraphicObject with a constructor of DecoratorLeft with passing the argument of the type GraphicObject. That's what i want to do, any ideas?

Comment: 'only null exception on this' Do you mean `NullPointerException` is thrown? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: @EJP I updated my previous post with stack trace?? I hope that's a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. There is no more lines to that stack-trace? Is that what is printed out by the `System.out.println(e)` line in the first code block?. Otherwise it could be that your code goes on, `decor` is left as  a `null` and so the exception when you try to use the first time.

Comment: @ValentinRuano Well I believe it does end there, because other calls just show at what time it happens. It is because the decor remains null. So any idea why it remains null? am I calling the constructor with reflection correctly?

Comment: I cannot conceive a constructor that would ever return a null. I can only assume that the stack trace that your have posted is not produced by the `System.out.println(e)` and is that exception `e` what you are after. In any case, I guess, it makes little sense to allow the program to continue if there was any problem during construction. I suggest that you re-throw the exception instead. Quick fix: add `e.printStackTrace(); throw new RuntimeException(e);` right after or even instead of the `System.out.println(e)` line. Check on what comes out from the standard error (terminal/console)

Comment: @ValentinRuano Hmm, I added those things to my try/catch now. What do you think of it new? What could be the reason for the value to remain null?

Comment: There is simply no way that a successful constructor invocation would return null. Is it is possible that those lines of code are simply never executed at all? What if you add `throw new java.lang.OutOfMemoryError()` before the `try`

Comment: Why not, also try `System.exit(1)` :-)... well Ideally you should use a good debugger at this point. If the app survives after this I reckon those lines are never accessed at all although perhaps security set-ups you can prevent some code to be able to call exit that way... not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it simpler, by just creating something like:

`protected GraphicObject getNewInstance ( GraphicObject decoratedGraphic ){
   ...
}`

inside your `GraphicObject` class, so every class inhereting it will have this method, and you can call it directly from the object.